# How to make a GUI map in Python

Tags: python, openstreetmap, tkinter

I'd like to build a GUI for map like this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzuiEnbVU2U but using OSM data.

I know the syntax of Tk, but have a problem to put the map inside. Need some advices/tips to load the map tile inside the window asynchronous and make it scrollable.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anyone still looking ways to build app with maps:

- https://github.com/TomSchimansky/TkinterMapView ->good to start
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/gis/
- https://realpython.com/python-folium-web-maps-from-data/